# Why doesn't Net::SNMP::Util::OID convert all of my textual OIDs to numeric OIDs?

Tags: perl, snmp

I'm trying to convert some OIDs I got from a trap to numeric dotted notation (like `1.3.6.1.2`) using [Net::SNMP::Util::OID](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP::Util::OID), but not all of them are converted. Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use Net::SNMP::Util::OID qw(*);

printf "%s\n", oid("DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance");
printf "%s\n", oid("sysDescr");
printf "%s\n", oid("SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0");
printf "%s\n", oid("IF-MIB::linkDown");
```

Output:

```
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0
IF-MIB::linkDown
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Net::SNMP::Util::OID uses a [hard-coded lookup table](https://metacpan.org/source/TONODERA/Net-SNMP-Util-1.04/lib/Net/SNMP/Util/OID.pm#L81), so it only works for certain OIDs in MIB-II and IF-MIB. For example, `IF-MIB::ifName` is included, while `IF-MIB::linkDown` isn't.

It doesn't allow you to prefix the MIB name, either, so

```
oid('ifName')
```

works while

```
oid('IF-MIB::ifName')
```

doesn't.

---

I would recommend using the [Perl API to the Net-SNMP library](https://metacpan.org/pod/SNMP) instead. It allows you to load arbitrary MIBs and translate OIDs from and into a variety of formats.

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.010;

use SNMP;

# Load a MIB not bundled with Net-SNMP
SNMP::addMibFiles('./Sentry3.mib');

my @names = qw(
    linkDown
    IF-MIB::linkDown
    SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0
    systemTotalPower
);

foreach my $name (@names) {
    say "$name: ", SNMP::translateObj($name);
}
```

Output:

```
linkDown: .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3
IF-MIB::linkDown: .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3
SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0: .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0
systemTotalPower: .1.3.6.1.4.1.1718.3.1.6
```